# Passing Variables Between States in Impromptu

Tags: jquery, impromptu

I'm currently using Impromptu for a form process on my site.  However, I'm having trouble with passing variable information between the different states.  I'm not entirely sure if it's even possible.  But what I would like for it to do is pull the variable information from the first state and display it in the second state's input box.  Can this be done?

Test code:

```
<script>

function stateAttempt(id){

    var displayDrop;

    var txt = '<div class="field"><label for="dropDownValueName">Drop:</label>'+
    '<select name="dropDownValueName">'+
    '<option value="DropDownValue">Drop Down Option</option>'+
    '</select>'+
    '</div>';

    var txtTwo = '<div class="field"><label for="address">Value:</label> <input type="text" id="address" name="address" value="'+ displayDrop +'" /></div>';

var statesdemo = {
    state0: {
        title: 'State One',
        html: txt,
        buttons: { Cancel:false, Next: 1 },
        submit:function(e,v,m,f){           
            if(v){  
                flag = true;
                if (flag == true) {

                    console.log(f);

                     window.displayDrop = f.dropDownValueName; 

                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.prompt.goToState('state1');

                } else { return false; }

            } else {                
                $.prompt.close();
            }
        }
    },
    state1: {
        title: 'State Two',
        html: txtTwo,
        buttons: { Cancel: 1, Back: -1 },
        submit:function(e,v,m,f){           
            if(v){  
                if (flag == true) {

                    console.log(f);

                    e.preventDefault();
                    if(v==1) $.prompt.close();
                    if(v==-1) $.prompt.goToState('state0');

                } else { return false; }

            } else {                
                $.prompt.close();
            }
        }
    },
};

$.prompt(statesdemo);
}

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="stateAttempt();">Display Prompt</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Geez, I've been working on this for hours and found adding this just before "$.prompt.goToState('state1');" works:

```
jQuery.prompt.getStateContent('state1').find('#address').val(f.dropDownValueName);
```